# android:slidingDrawer not showing listview content?

Tags: android

I hvae a sliding drawer in which i tried to list a listview. My problem is listview contents not showing in side sliding drawer.But outside of this ,its working perfectly.My code shows below.

```
    <SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:handle="@+id/handle"
    android:content="@+id/content"><Button
        android:id="@id/handle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:text="Notification"
        android:background="@drawable/notification"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" 
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_height="27dp" 
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
          />    <LinearLayout 
     android:id="@+id/notificationLayout"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"android:background="#fff"><ListView
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_weight="1"/> 
<TextView
        android:id="@id/content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#8c8c8c"
        android:gravity="bottom"
         android:visibility="gone"
        android:text=""/>
    </LinearLayout> </SlidingDrawer>
```

Augustine

Comment: Same issue is to me also, share the answer. marked answer not giving solution to me. and the link is also unavailable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to put the listview inside a LinearLayout with @id/content.

```
    <LinearLayout android:id="@id/content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="Below there is a list view." />

        <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/listview_"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent" 
            android:dividerHeight="10.0sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

In onCreate()

```
    // add some data
    ArrayList<MyData> myDataList = new ArrayList<MyData>();
    ....
    myDataList.add(one);
    ....

    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_);

    mListView.setAdapter(new MyListAdapter(this, R.layout.row, myDataList));
```

Comment: when i put linearlayout as @id/content ,its not working.any other change i want to make.

Comment: Would recommend you to look at the example again. Extend Activity instead of ListActivity and grab the ListView with id listview_